# jQuery Accordion - how to have all tabs initially closed

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

Have a simple FAQ Accordion structure and managed to make the description open / close when hovering on the title, but can't manage to have all tabs (descriptions) initially closed.

I read something about setting the collapsible to true and the active to false but can't manage to make that work. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion"> 
    <div id="title1">Title 1</div>
    <div id="description1">Description 1</div>

    <div id="title2">Title 2</div>
    <div id="description2">Description 2</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#title1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#description1').slideToggle('slow', function(){
    });
})

$('#title2').mouseover(function(){
    $('#description2').slideToggle('slow', function(){
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can use DRY principles to simplify your code. By using common classes on your elements you can simplify your JS code to work for any number of elements. Currently, you would have to add an event handler for each new title/description added. Try this:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="title">Title 1</div>
    <div class="description">Description 1</div>

    <div class="title">Title 2</div>
    <div class="description">Description 2</div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.title').hover(function () {
    $(this).next('.description').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Note that I used the `hover` event, as this will also close the related `.description` element on mouseout.

You can then hide all the `.description` elements on page load using CSS:

```
.description {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7CYHF/1)

Comment: Works perfectly. Also added a Open all / Hide all option inside a div with id="switch". For the CSS I created 2 classes .show {display: block;} and .hide {display: none;}. Not sure how to write the jQuery for this behavior and how to switch the text from Open all when tabs are closed and Hide all when they are opened.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JQuery's each function to iterate through all elements that start with the "description" id and hide them:

```
$('[id^=description]').each(function(i,e){
       $(e).hide();   
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3HX5/)